# Angular: Lazy load component from external library

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

With Angular Ivy it became possible to lazy-load single components rather than modules.

To make this happen, components should be generated with `--skip-import` flag.

I was wondering if it was possible even if the lazy-loaded component is part of an external library.

Has anyone tried it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you expecting a `yes/no`, or did you run into a problem?

Comment: It's a Y/N question with maybe an explanation of how to define the external library to make it work and what path to use in the application to load the component.
I still haven't tried, I want to be sure it is possible before touching the code

Comment: What do you mean with ‘external’? You would still need the module containing the component inside your project right..?

Comment: sure, I mean, how can I lazy load a component imported from a third-party library?

Comment: @IginoBoffa I have tired the same senario, I cannot able to achieve. Please let know how to implement that.. 
I struggling in "what path to use to load component from external component"